# Where to find the optimization sequence for clang -OX?

Tags: clang, llvm

Where can I find the sequence of optimizations used by clang according to -OX?

Comment: Apart from the source code, that is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

clang executes the precisely same sequence of passes as opt -ON. So, you can do something like

```
llvm-as < /dev/null | opt -O3 -disable-output -debug-pass=Arguments
```

to derive the "full" set of passes which are run at O3.

Comment: But I only see up to O3 in opt. Why clang has O4?

Comment: -O4 usually means link-time optimization, thus it cannot be performed via opt alone. The set of passes suitable for LTO can be found via opt -std-link-opts.

Comment: Thanks! I parsed and posted the output for all optimization levels [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15548189/762488) for llvm 3.2