# big functions do not inline llvm -inline pass

Tags: llvm, inline, llvm-clang

It seems like llvm `-inline` pass only inlines small functions. Is there a way to inline all functions, no matter how big they are?

Comment: Inlining was created to inline small functions. Why do you want to inline big ones?

Comment: i need to do some experiments on programs, but i cannot work with function calls.

Comment: Can i force inline every function??

Comment: to my mind, it's useless as some functions simply cannot be inlined (for example, `main` LOL). Moreover, clang's smart enough to inline every function possible when you request it. I think it does its best when you ask it to do it.

Comment: You can use the `always_inline` attribute and then the run the `-always-inline` pass (as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602813/force-a-function-to-be-inline-in-clang-llvm)). That requires you to annotate every function though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-inline-threshold` flag to change the "cost" up to which LLVM will inline a function. A higher value means more functions will be inlined.

`opt -inline -inline-threshold=10000 ...`

Obviously functions can not always be inlined, particularly when the call graph contains cycles (recursive calls).

Comment: Is there any other reason (except for recursion) due to which a function might not get inlined ??

Comment: Indirect function calls are not being inlined. Any help regarding that?