# Is there any way to tell clang to generate TBAA metadata without other optimizations?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

LLVM contains an alias analysis named "type based alias analysis"([pass source code on github](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Analysis/TypeBasedAliasAnalysis.cpp)), which utilizes the `!tbaa` metadata embedded with the instruction. The metadata information is like:

```
!1 = metadata !{metadata !2, metadata !2, i64 0}
!2 = metadata !{metadata !"int", metadata !3, i64 0}
!3 = metadata !{metadata !"omnipotent char", metadata !4, i64 0}
!4 = metadata !{metadata !"Simple C/C++ TBAA"}
```

It seems that it requires the frontend like clang to generate the metadata information.

Compiling source code file without passing any optimization arguments(or `-O0`) cannot generate the above metadata. And till now I only find that I have to pass at least `-O1` to clang to get these; the problem is that I don't expect other optimizations/transformations(e.g., [instcombine](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#instcombine-combine-redundant-instructions)) to happen(the passes used by `clang -O1` is similar to the results presented by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796151/where-to-find-the-optimization-sequence-for-clang-ox/7807152#7807152)).

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I don't know a simple way, but one alternative is to enable -O1 then explicitly disable each option that -O1 enables

Comment: @technosaurus you mean within clang? Can you tell how to disable that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15548189/1162141

Comment: @technosaurus yes, i think that thread should be help. i'm trying using `-mllvm` option but still haven't found the way to enable tbaa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest it for production use, but you can do something like this:

clang -cc1 -O1 -no-struct-path-tbaa -disable-llvm-optzns foo.cpp -emit-llvm -o -

to take a look at the TBAA metadata (remove the -no-struct-path-tbaa if you want to look at that as well).

Otherwise you could modify clang pretty easily to always turn on TBAA metadata.

Comment: Thanks, it works smoothly. I just wanna some experiments on LLVM TBAA for C and don't expect for production use, so that's enough for me. BTW, may I know your opinion on implementation of current LLVM type-based alias analysis?

Comment: It's fine, the struct path stuff is a little interesting. It's not state of the art, but it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a bit out of date. I believe `-disable-llvm-optzns` is deprecated/removed. You can do this with the driver using something like this:

`clang -O2 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -S -emit-llvm`